# Fatal error after brew update and brew upgrade

Tags: homebrew

```
$ brew update
Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/Library/Formula/abyss-explorer.rb

$ brew upgrade
==> Upgrading 20 outdated packages, with result:
ant 1.9.4, automake 1.14.1, elasticsearch 1.2.0, erlang R16B03-1, gd 2.1.0_2, git 1.9.3, gnuplot 4.6.5, ios-sim 1.9.0, leiningen 2.3.4, libgpg-error 1.13, libpng 1.6.10, libyaml 0.1.6, maven 3.2.1, mongodb 2.6.1, openssl 1.0.1g, python 2.7.6_1, readline 6.3.5, redis 2.8.9, sqlite 3.8.4.3, wget 1.15_1
==> Upgrading ant
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/ant-1.9.4.mavericks.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring ant-1.9.4.mavericks.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/ant/1.9.4: 1597 files, 39M
==> Upgrading automake
Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/share/doc/automake
```

Comment: Please try and explain your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Homebrew needs /usr/local/ to be owned by you:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, when you experience an error with Homebrew, a good place to start debugging is to run `brew doctor`.  It often suggests some solutions.  It looks like you haven't tried that yet, so if you get into trouble, start there.

You can also consult [the Homebrew web page](http://brew.sh/), [the Homebrew wiki](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki), and [the Homebrew troubleshooting page](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki).  If you consult those resources, you'll find suggestions to run `brew doctor` and to set the permissions on `/usr/local`... as well as other suggestions.

So, please try those first, if you get into trouble again in the future.